# In SQLite, how do I reference a key multiple levels deep?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

Given a MAC id element from the table below, what would be the best way to retrieve its associated device?

[image: Table Sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look up the IDs with subqueries:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Devices
WHERE id = (SELECT parent
            FROM Interfaces
            WHERE id = (SELECT parent_interface_id
                        FROM MAC
                        WHERE mac = ? ));
```

or with joins:

```sql
SELECT Devices.*
FROM Devices
JOIN Interfaces ON Devices.id    = Interfaces.parent
JOIN MAC        ON Interfaces.id = MAC.parent_interface_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!